# sites/default/files should be accessable from root drupal 6

Tags: file, drupal-6, alias

A file called "test.php" file which is placed in sites/default/files should be accessible from root i.e www.example.com/test.php using drupal 6.

Can any one help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your php file did not run because in sites/default/files folder there is a .htaccess file which disables the php handler to execute php files. This is a normal behavior. It is what happens on all my sites.

The change in behavior in "files" is caused by the small .htaccess files which Drupal puts there for security reasons (to disable the php handler). Thats why your **test.php** is not working.

If you are a bit curious, then run your file and check the file source, you will see your php code is still there.

For more: http://drupal.org/node/814890, http://drupal.org/node/652002

Comment: Actually, i saved my test.html file in "sites/default/files/test.html" and is it possible to access as http://www.example.com/test.html?

Comment: @user2138582, yes, you can access *.html files in  "sites/default/files/" but for *,php you cannot.

Comment: place the test.html file at public_html/root folder where the sites folder resides.

Comment: Sorry, I was asked to put my html files in files folder and access as if they are from root folder using drupa alias...I tried but no use.

Comment: If that's the requirement I think you're doing it the hard way. There are easier ways of doing this, like creating your own module, implementing `hook_menu` to register paths and `hook_theme` for the templates. That way your fully integrated with Drupal, rather than just serving some PHP files from `sites/default/files` which has a totally different purpose.